# Проблема подписи приложения в xcode

Tags: xcode, signature

Добрый день сегодня столкнулся с проблемой вот такого рода:

Захотел проверить программу на реальном устройстве, подключил телефон (айфон 5, iOS 9.3) указал устройство сам телефон, нажал плей и он мне выдал вот такую ошибку:

> Unable to add App ID because the '10' App ID limit in '7' days  has
>   been exceeded.

Искал в нете ничего нет.
Так же пытался указать Team на none он мне пишет, что нужна команда и указывается на мой Apple iD.
Смотреть в настройках и приложения и самих настройках xcode ничего тоже не нашел

Я вот не могу понять зачем это подписывание нужно мне на данном этапе, я просто хотел бы посмотреть на работу приложения на реальном устройстве [image: Скрин]